# Proxy post data in php

Tags: php, mysql, proxy

Good afternoon.

We have a form in HTML that will ask for some personal details. The "action" points to our CRM's capture file, so it can add user's data to our CRM. This works perfectly.

Now, we want to add our user's data to a mysql database before sending it to the CRM (we cannot change the CRM capture file).
Therefore it should change from: Form -> CRM
To: Form -> "proxy page" -> CRM
The "proxy page" should add the data to a mysql database before sending it to the CRM. It should forward the POST exactly as it receives it.

I got the code to write to mysql, I just need to know how to do the proxy page forward the post.

Here is part of our form code:

```html
<form name="myform" action="CRM.com/capture.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table> 
    <tbody> 
      <tr> 
        <td> 
          <label>First Name*</label></td> 
        <td> <input name="firstname" data-label="First Name" required="" type="text" /> </td> 
      </tr> 
      <tr> 
        <td> 
          <label>Last Name*</label></td> 
        <td> <input name="lastname" data-label="Last Name" required="" type="text" /> </td> 
      </tr> 
        <td><input type="image" value="Download" src="/content/files/boton-landing.jpg" /></td> 
      </tr>
    </tbody> 
  </table> </form>
```

Anyone can help? Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Point an Ajax script to your PHP script and parse the values as normal in PHP

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is send two ajax requests instead of just the one. If you for instance use jQuery, you can bind the submit event of your form to a function where you first send the users data to your own server where you store the data in a databse, and a second post where you send the data to the CRM.

What you could also do is just change the action to your own server and store the users data in a database, after which you send an http request to the CRM server.

Both solutions work, I don't think it matters which one you decide on. Ithink doing it with jQuery is the easiest though.

Comment: Thanks Glubus. How would you do that in the code above? I don't have any experience with jquery

Comment: JQuery is a library for javasaript that is widely used everywhere. It's not best practice but in order to add javascript to your html page, you put it in between <script></script> tags. 
Im sure you understand that Im not going to write this entire script for you (even though it's only 10 minutes work I think). Search the web on how to import jquery into your page and look for a function called $.post().

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
$("myform#data").submit(function(event){

  //disable the default form submission
  event.preventDefault();

  //grab all form data  
  var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

  $.ajax({
url: 'parse.php',
type: 'POST',
data: formData,
async: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function (returndata) {
  alert(returndata);
}
  });

  return false;
});
</script>
```

The above code will parse your PHP script and return any errors that you want to pull from it onto the main page without refresh.

Excuse the mess it was sent on my phone.

Comment: Hi Filty_Rich. I have had a look at the code and actually tried it and, besides it doesn't seem to work, at least the way I expect, it does not apply to our problem. Does it?
It's highly possible that I'm not getting the point you may be trying to make, but what we want to do is receive the POST in a new PHP file, work with the data (copy to MYSQL) and then forward the POST to a second PHP page just like it received it.